# How to debug linux networking: Address already in use

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have a Slackware linux box where I cannot start any service that listens on one particular port on localhost. By using strace I found out that the error happens on the `bind()` call, and the error is `EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`:

`bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(874), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`

This happens with any process I try to start listening on that port, so it is not related to the process itself. The above strace output comes from the command `strace -ff nc -l -p 874 -s 127.0.0.1`.

So, this suggests there is a process already listening on localhost port 874. However, I can't seem to find it. The following commands all return nothing:

```
netstat -aplunt | grep :874
netstat -na | grep :874
lsof -i :874
lsof -i tcp | grep 874
fuser 874/tcp
socklist | grep 874
iptables -t filter -S | grep 874
iptables -t nat -S | grep 874
iptables -t mangle -S | grep 874
conntrack -L | grep 874
```

If I try to listen on `0.0.0.0:874` it fails with the same error. Listening on one of the IP addresses configured on a nic works OK, and listening to `127.0.0.2:874` also works OK. Listening on a different port works fine, also on `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`.

So, now I am curious. How can I find out why the network stack returns EADDRINUSE here? What other things could I look at, or what other commands can I run to get more information?

Additional info:

- Kernel 4.1.31.
- Selinux is not used here.
- Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 with telnet returns "Connection refused"
- I'm running the commands as root

Comment: Can you check if there is no established sessions on that port? Run **netstat -aplunt | grep 874**, just add 'a' flag. Or maybe some session using this port as the source port?(Although highly unlikely). But worth giving a shot.

Comment: No output. I've updated the netstat command in the question.

Comment: Is the port mentioned anywhere in `iptables -S` output?

Comment: I think @hertitu is right, it may be port forwarding in iptables. Also use `nmap` to check 874 tcp and udp port. What ip has localhost in /etc/hosts file? Check all configs in /etc and /usr/local/etc folders that they have 874 substring.

Comment: @hertitu how would portforwarding affect listening on a port? Anyway, I checked, and there are no iptables rules for that port. To be extra sure I flushed the firewall: no change.

Comment: Can you please also print output of **strace -ff nc -l  874** also, The one you used is trying to make connections with 874 as source port. Thanks!

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I'm not making a connection, I'm **listening** on port 874, which is where the problem is. The command you showed listens on a random high port. There is no problem doing that.

Comment: Well here is what the man page of nc states:
**-p source_port
             Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.

-l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an
             error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w
             option are ignored.**

you cannot these flags in conjunction. So I will correct myself the command you used is rather contradictory. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps we have a different version of nc? Mine says: **-l**: listen mode, for inbound connects, **-p port**: local port number.

Comment: AFAIK Linux requires root privileges when listening to a port < 1000. Maybe that's the problem here.

Comment: Anyway, I have the same problem if I use a different process to listen: **rsync --daemon --address=127.0.01 --port=874**

Comment: I'm running all commands as root. Question updated.

Comment: Is this host an NFS client? It may be using source port 874 for an NFS mount. Anyway I would try `netstat -na | grep 874` in case your current `netstat` flags are too restrictive.

Comment: @TomShaw You just made my day! It was **NFS** all right. I'm not sure how this exactly came about, but after unmounting all NFS mounts and restarting the RPC and NFS services the problem is gone. With tcpdump I also saw some traffic from port 874 to port 111 (why didn't I think of that before) which confirms it. Can you post this as an answer please?

Comment: finally pheww... TCPdump(ughh, should have thought about earlier). Glad it worked though.

Comment: Glad I could help, posted as an answer with some ways of mitigating the issue. P.S. On my machine the NFS connections are visible in the `netstat -na` output, albeit without associated processes (because they come from the kernel). They can't be seen with commands like `lsof` or `fuser`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your host is an NFS client, it may be using source port 874 for an NFS mount. I suspect that because the connection does not originate from userspace it may not be visible to the tools you've used so far.

Consider one of the following:

- Adjust the `sysctl`s `sunrpc.min_resvport` and `sunrpc.max_resvport` (default 665 and 1023) to change the range of source ports that the NFS client uses
- Use a listening port outside of this range
- Use the `noresvport` option on the NFS mount to use the non-privileged range (may have security implications)